# How to tell when query executed successfully in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I test to see if the following query executed successfully?

```
$STH = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE UserCreds SET
    VerificationString=:newVerificationString, ExpiryDate=:expiryDate 
    WHERE UserID = :userID;");
$STH->execute($params);
```

I know I can use `lastInsertId()` when I'm adding new rows, but what about UPDATEs and SELECTs?

Comment: @Pekka Nope, I can get error messages just fine.

Comment: http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php says: *Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.* - So bind it to a variable, e.g. `$success = $STH->execute($params);` and check that variable against `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `execute` returns `true` on success and `false` on failure.

[From Docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

---

So you can make sure query ran successfully like:

```
if ($STH->execute($params))
{
  // success
}
else
{
  // failure
}
```

Comment: So something like `if($STH->execute($params)) { echo "Success!"; } else { echo "Failure!"; } `?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Yes you are right :) You can also store result of `execute` in a variable if you need to use that later.

Comment: Works great for just checking (technical) success. Use `rowCount()` to check whether anything has changed in an `UPDATE` (the `mysql` driver will also tell you how much rows are in a `SELECT` with it, but this shouldn't be relied upon).

Comment: If you test for type it doesn't work.  E.G.
if( $STH->execute($params) === true )

Will fail, every time.  At least when the execute if for creating a new mysql user.  Returns int(0) on success, and null on failure.  Why is that?

Comment: how do you get the error message to help figure out why it failed?

Answer (score 18):

execute() returns true/false based on success/failure of the query:

```
$status = $STH->execute($params);

if ($status) {
   echo 'It worked!';
} else {
   echo 'It failed!';
}
```

One note: a select query which returns no rows is NOT a failure. It's a perfectly valid result that just happens to have NO results.

Answer (score 8):

simply i can count the number of row effected:

```
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count =='0'){
    echo "Failed !";
}
else{
    echo "Success !";
}
```

Comment: This only works when using UPDATE

Comment: yes this is for UPDATE, look at the query which asked, it looks about UPDATE

Comment: The question specifically states: "what about UPDATEs and SELECTs?"

Answer (score -3):

This is best way to verify Doctrine query result return success or failed
result and same way as per above suggest to check weather query 
returns **Success on True** and **Failed on false**.

```
    public static function removeStudent($teacher_id){
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->delete('Student s')
            ->where('s.teacher_id = ?');

        $result = $q->execute(array($teacher_id));

        if($result)
        {
         echo "success";
        }else{
         echo "failed";
        }
    }
```